# Two Validation Groups in a single button without client click event

Tags: asp.net, validation, customvalidator

In a multigrid I am validating two controls like date and amount. It is validating correctly when I press the tabevent. When I press the save button it is not validating. I am using two validations groups and two validation summary. Then in save button Ialso tried `onclientclick()` function with javascript it is working fine but if I give the correct value in date and amount records, it is not saving. how to over come this.

### Date

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Text='<%# Bind("AD_REF_DATE") %>' runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
                                                                ValidationGroup="group" Width="80px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="dateValidater" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
                                                                Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ValidationGroup="group" EnableClientScript="true"
                                                                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date (mm/dd/yyyy)." SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

### Amount

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" MaxLength="17" Text='<%# Bind("AD_AMOUNT") %>' CausesValidation="true"
                                                                ValidationGroup="req" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regVal1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmount"
                                                                ErrorMessage="Format(13int,5deci)" ValidationExpression="^[1-9]\d{0,12}(\.\d{1,2})?%?$"
                                                                ValidationGroup="req" Display="None"  EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="true">
                                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

### validations summary:

```
 <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="req"
                            HeaderText="Amount:Invalid Format" DisplayMode="BulletList" ShowMessageBox="true"
                            ShowSummary="false" />
                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group"
                            HeaderText="Date:Invalid Format" DisplayMode="BulletList"  ShowMessageBox="true" 
                            ShowSummary="false" />
```

### button save:

```
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server"  CssClass="button" CausesValidation="true" Text="<%$Resources:TJFAS501, ButtonSave %>"
                                            OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" TabIndex="6" />
```

How to validate this in the button save also two popup box should be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try firing the validate function for both groups manually via the button's `OnClientClick` since you have two validation groups you need to validate against.  Currently your validation is not firing because you do not have any `ValidationGroup` assigned to your button so it is just looking for validators with no `ValidationGroup` defined (yours groups are: group and req).

You can call `Page_ClientValidate()` via javascript to fire off the validation checks manually (be sure to set `CauseValidation` on your button to false) and it has an optional parameter that takes the validation group.

```
<asp:Button ID="yourButton" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click"
    CausesValidation="false" TabIndex="6"
    OnClientClick="return (Page_ClientValidate('group') && Page_ClientValidate('req'));" />
```

You can read more about `Page_ClientValidate` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx).

It would be easier to just have one validation group for each action (eg. your button) but I assume you need two groups for some reason.

Comment: I tried using this but in my second validation group there is Javascript function on `ClientValidationFunction` of `CustomValidator` is not being executing or called

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function Validate() {
            var isValid = false;
            isValid = Page_ClientValidate('Group1');
            if (isValid) {
                isValid = Page_ClientValidate('Group2');
            } 
            return isValid;
        }
    </script>
```